# Session bean in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, el

I store my user info into a session bean like this :

```
@Component
@Scope( value="session" , proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public class UserInfos {

    public List<Integer> roles;
    public Integer idUser;


    public List<Integer> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<Integer> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public Integer getIdUser() {
        return idUser;
    }
    public void setIdUser(Integer idUser) {
        this.idUser = idUser;
    }


}
```

In my controller I put the bean in the session as a attribute :

```
@Controller
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private UserInfos userInfos;

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo/login") 
    public String  login_foo(HttpServletRequest request){
        ....
        userInfos.idUser = ...
        userInfos.roles  = ...

        request.getSession().setAttribute( "userInfos", userInfos );
        ....
    }
}
```

But when i try to use it in `jsp` page the value of `${ sessionScope.userInfos.idUser }` is always `null`.

When I try

```
(${ sessionScope.userInfos }) - (${ sessionScope.userInfos.idUser })
```

I got this :

```
(beans.UserInfos@445541fc) - ()
```

So how can I use the properties of a session bean in JSP page ?

Because when i debug in my controller the value of `userInfos.idUser` is not null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

We solve it by replacing :

```
    userInfos.idUser = ...
    userInfos.roles  = ...
```

By :

```
    userInfos.setIdUser( ... );
    userInfos.setRoles( ... );
```

If someone can explain me why that work with setting properties it will be very usefull.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that maybe Spring is proxying your bean through a dynamic proxy object. But, as Spring always expect the objects to behave as **java beans** (private variables, public getters and setters), the public methods are being intercepted, while the public variables are not (because they can not). So, remember to let the variable members always as **private**.